# Delay a certain function without stopping entire program // Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, delay

As of right now, I am working on developing a simple clicker game for fun. I would like to be able to run an auto-clicker that automatically adds X clicks to your total w/ say a 1 second delay in-between each time. My problem is that if I try to delay, and/or not and run an auto-clicker, it will freeze the entire program. I have read about how threads work, but am not completely understanding how to do it in Swift 4.

Here is what I have so far

```
@IBAction func auto_clicker_add(_ sender: Any)
{
    while auto_clicker_switch.isOn == true
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)
        {
            self.count_taps = self.count_taps + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace the `while` loop and `asyncAfter` with a `Timer`.

Comment: Off topic, but you should consider renaming your functions and variables with [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a little care be exercised to avoid strong references to the view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tapCount = 0

    // I'd suggest weak reference to timer so that when it's invalidated, this is automatically set to `nil`

    weak var timer: Timer?

    // if view controller is dismissed, stop the timer (if it hasn't already been stopped)

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    // switch to turn timer on or off has changed

    @IBAction func toggleTimer(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        timer?.invalidate()

        if sender.isOn {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.tapCount += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the key points are:

1. The block-based rendition of timers get you out of the confusing `target`/`selector` syntax.
2. When you use `target`/`selector` approach, a running timer keeps a strong reference to the `target` which means if you dismiss the view controller, the timer will keep going and the view controller won't be released. Using the closure-based rendition of the timer in conjunction with `[weak self]` pattern ensures that the timer won't keep a strong reference to the view controller.
3. Because the timer no longer keeps a strong reference to the view controller, we can now use `deinit` to make sure that if the view controller is dismissed, that the timer will be stopped, too.

Answer (score 2):

Like my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100426/swift-incrementing-label-with-delay/49101701#49101701), here is an alternative solution instead of `DispatchQueue`:

```
var timer: Timer?

@IBAction func auto_clicker_add(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    if (auto_clicker_switch.isOn == true) {
        self.count_taps += 1
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

This uses `Timer` in Swift.

P.S. Although it's not very related to the question, you should consider renaming your variables and functions in camel case rather than snake case.

Comment: On ||            @IBAction func auto_clicker_add(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}               || I get an error, "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'updateTimer'.". Oh and to anyone who is trying the solution, make sure to force unwrap timer?.invalidate()

Comment: @cyph4r I think that Dan Karbayev's answer is good, but mine is a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
// a little bit more meaningful name
var autoClickTimer: Timer?

@IBAction func auto_clicker_add(_ sender: Any) {
  if auto_clicker_switch.isOn {
    // make sure that timer wasn't set yet
    guard self.autoClickTimer == nil else { return }
    self.autoClickTimer = setInterval(1) { [unowned self] in
      self.count_taps += 1
    }
  } else {
    self.autoClickTimer?.invalidate()
    self.autoClickTimer = nil
  }
}

// helper function (credits: http://peatiscoding.me/uncategorized/javascript-settimeout-swift-3-0/)
func setInterval(_ interval: TimeInterval, execute: @escaping () -> Void) -> Timer {
  return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: BlockOperation(block: execute), selector: #selector(Operation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```